# Google play is not displaying my app for tablets?

Tags: android, tablet, google-play

I would like to display my app for tablets as well,what are the necessary steps needed to be followed so that my app do get listed for tablet as well.Already my app is been listed for mobile phones.Am I missing something here,please do provide your help.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write Below Code into your Androidmanifest.xml file

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />
```

Comment: Adding the above code to the manifest,due to that do we need to make changes in our xml layout..

Answer (score 1):

see the step given **Address compatibility issues** and 
What all changes made in `Manifest.xml` **Review and update your manifest settings** http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/preparing.html

How to support Multi screen? http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

This steps will indirect leads to show your app for Tablets too.