# Android Multiple Screen Support for tablet

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"     
    android:layout_height="450dp"     
    android:background="#f8f9fe" >      

    <LinearLayout       
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"       
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"              
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                   
        android:orientation="vertical" >                  

        <LinearLayout                  
            android:id="@+id/extremelysorry"                  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"                  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                 
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"                    
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"                        
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"            
            android:background="@drawable/pressicon"        
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView     
                android:id="@+id/extremelysorry1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="  &quot;We are extremely sorry, request your valuable ."
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/pressicon"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/signetno"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:text=" Please enter your Loyalty Card No/Name,Mobile No/Name "
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="20dip"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayout03"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="250dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/labelbg" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/loyaltyLable"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:text="Membership Card No."
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textSize="20dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/ed_cardno"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/textbox_n"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="Touch here to enter"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoExtractUi"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textSize="20dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_age"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="250dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/labelbg" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:text="Name"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textSize="20dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ed_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:autoText="true"
                android:background="@drawable/textbox_n"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Touch here to enter"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoExtractUi"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_emailid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/labelbg" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Mobile No"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ed_mobileno"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/textbox_n"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="10digit Mobile number"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoExtractUi"
                android:numeric="integer"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:phoneNumber="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_cardno"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/labelbg" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Email ID"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ed_emailid"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/textbox_n"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Touch here to enter"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoExtractUi"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_comeagain"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button
                android:id="@+id/back"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:background="@drawable/back_button"
                android:textColor="#ff29549f" />

                <Button
                android:id="@+id/comment_next"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="37dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="420dp"
                android:background="@drawable/next_button"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:textColor="#ff29549f" />

            <Chronometer
                android:id="@+id/start_quiz_time1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3.19"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/pressicon"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/manadatory"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:text="  *Mandatory: The information is confidential &amp; will not"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dip" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my code, but it does not support multiple screen. Widgets get displaced.

How to change this code as if I run this on any tablet, it'll looks the same on every tablet with different screen sizes and density?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are setting the size in dp for the layout height and width.

You need look more about weight, with that your layout will adjust in the screen size.

Answer (score 1):

Write Below Code into your Androidmanifest.xml file

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />
```

And see below link for more information.

[Screen Size Supports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891486/google-play-is-not-displaying-my-app-for-tablets/10891758#10891758)

Answer (score 1):

There are two important parameters which needs to taken cared when you are designing an app which
should run on multiple devices:

- size(physical size of the device)
- density of the device

Size: Size of a device in android is not defined as a unique physical value but as a range.
These are: small, normal, large and xlarge.

Density: Density is also defined as a range.
These are: ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi.

[image]

For handling size you need to use have multiple layouts, one for each category of the size and you need to use different dp value for the height and width of the views for each of the layout as the sizeof a small and a large device will not be same.

For handling density you need to using different drawables for different screen densities i.e you need to place different density drawables in different drawable folders.
Eg: 
These are the resolutions for a particular drawable

- 36x36 for low-density (placed in drawable-ldpi)
- 48x48 for medium-density (placed in drawable-mdpi)
- 72x72 for high-density (placed in drawable-hdpi)
- 96x96 for extra high-density (placed in drawable-xhdpi)

The ratio for this variation of the resolution is 3:4:6:8(ldpi:mdpi:hdpi:xhdpi)

For further reading you can refer to this android developer's link: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html